# How to make PyInstaller work on wxPython using 2 stage creation with XRC?

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller, xrc

Everyone suggests switch from py2exe to PyInstaller for making a standalone executable from Python scripts. Our first trial is to make a wxPython application which makes usage of lots of [2 stage creation with XRC](http://wiki.wxpython.org/TwoStageCreation). It seems the building process of PyInstaller doesn't include those modules specified in .xrc files and I am wondering if we can utilize hidden imports feature or other alternatives. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

PyInstaller's documentation also explains how to include and exclude stuff:

http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/latest/tags/1.4/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#create-a-spec-file-for-your-project

My guess is you need to explicitly include wx.xrc

Comment: Interestly, I still couldn't figure out how to ask PyInstaller include some modules explicitly cause my issues is not wx.xrc, but the declared subclass in some .xrc files.

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample app?